# Is it possible to reverse the order in a listview?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

When I get my data from the firebase realtime database it is automatically listed in ascending order, but I'm trying to get the values that I put into an arraylist to be listed in reverse order rather that ascending.

Is it possible to get a reverse order on values when working with a listview ?
Code in use at the moment is:

```
    Query query = userRef.orderByChild("totalNumberOfSteps");
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String username = ds.child("username").getValue(String.class);
                long totalNumberOfSteps = ds.child("totalNumberOfSteps").getValue(Long.class);
                Log.d(TAG , username + " - Steps: " + totalNumberOfSteps);
                arrayList.add(new String(username + "  -  " + "steps:  " + totalNumberOfSteps));

                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Leaderboard.this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , arrayList);

                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG , databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
        }
    };
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);}}
```

The current output of this code is:

```
John Doe VI - Steps: 0
John Doe III - Steps: 0
John Doe V - Steps: 12
John Doe I - Steps: 79
John Doe IV - Steps: 88
John Doe II - Steps: 111
```

Preferred output:

```
John Doe II - Steps: 111
John Doe IV - Steps: 88
John Doe I - Steps: 79
John Doe V - Steps: 12
John Doe III - Steps: 0
John Doe VI - Steps: 0
```

When adding `Collections.reverse(arrayList);` to the code, the output is:

```
John Doe II - Steps: 111
John Doe IV - Steps: 88
John Doe III - Steps: 0
John Doe VI - Steps: 0
John Doe V - Steps: 12
John Doe I - Steps: 79
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse the ArrayList before providing it to the ArrayAdapter by doing so:

```
Collections.reverse(arrayList);
```

In your case copy `arrayList` before reversing it and passing it to the ArrayAdapter's constructor:

```
ArrayList<> tmpArr = new ArrayList<>(arrayList);
Collections.reverse(tmpArr);
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Leaderboard.this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , tmpArr );
```

Otherwise the `arrayList` object will get reversed every time onDataChange() gets called and its order will get mixed up.

Comment: When adding `Collections.reverse(arrayList);` to my code, it does indeed reverse the order, but not entirely, I'll edit my question for you to see

Comment: What is your result when copying the ArrayList before reversing it?

`ArrayList<> tmpArr = new ArrayList<>(arrayList);
Collections.reverse(tmpArr);`

(use tmpArr for the adapter)

Comment: without adding that line, it is in ascending order as seen in the current output listed in the question.

Comment: Ok. What's the result when using the code of my previous comment? (use tmpArr for the ArrayAdapter)

Comment: By using tmpArr should I remove the current `arrayAdapter` which is in use ?   kinda confused at the moment

Comment: No, just try changing the last argument of the arrayAdapter's constructor from arrayList to tmpArr like so
`arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Leaderboard.this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , tmpArr);`

Comment: Works like a charm!                                                                                                            Can't express my gratitude in words haha, thank you very much!